# How to get environment variables from AWS elasticbeanstalk to pom file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pom.xml

Can someone tell me how can I get AWS elasticbeanstalk environment variables from tomcat software config to pom file?
I have tried using `env.propertyName` but it did not work. Also I read somewhere that it is the system variables that are set in the EBS software config for tomcat.
I also tried editing `tomcat8.conf` in `/usr/share/tomcat8` and entered the variables in that file, still it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use them in .xml configuration files like this ${database.username}
and declare variable like database.username but pom.xml I don't think that is possible because pom.xml is just here to describe how to compile your .war .jar .ear etc application

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty straightforward... Let's say I want to set a `JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING` property...

1. Go to your environment -> Configuration

[image: Go to the Configuration option in your Environment]

2. Go to the Environment Properties section and then define your `JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING` property.

[image]

3. Use it in pom.xml like `${JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}`

[image]

It works for my everytime :)

Comment: I tried this too.
Its giving me 404 everytime,
I am using jdbc and it says that it didn't receive any packets from the DB.

Comment: then that's something else, if it is not setting the property it will give you an error while compiling, what's the error?